# Is it possible to determine f(7)if f(x) = 3 for all x < 7 and f is right-continuous at x = 7? What if f is left-continuous?

Tags: limits

[image]

I am having a hard time really understanding the question, but what I am gathering is if the question had said "f(x)=3 for all x GREATER THAN 7" then we would be able to determine f(7) because it is right continuous until it gets to 3? Which 3 would be our value for f(7) in the new condition I created?

Maybe I just need a rewording of the question.

Comment: yes. if f(x)=3 for all x greater than 7 and is right continuous at 7, then f(7)=3 the first part tells you it's a flat line to the right of 7 (with an open dot at x=7), and the second part tells you to close the dot at x=7.

Comment: In the question text, $ f(x)=3$ for $x<7$ not greater...

Comment: my comment was a response to the op's typed question

Comment: Textbook solution says no. I have it in the photo.

Comment: I was addressing your conjecture, not the textbook problem!!!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem tells you $y=3$ for $x<7$. This is the first picture. $\lim_{x\rightarrow7-}f(x)=3$ However you need some information about continuity to determine more about the problem.

Now, if y is continuous from the left, as you MENTIONED IN YOUR POST AS A CONJECTURE, you can conclude that $f(7)=\lim_{x\rightarrow7-}f(x)=3$.

But if you are told y is continuous on the right, AS STATED IN THE PROBLEM, it's not necessarily the case that $f(7)=3$. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 7+}f(x)=L=f(7)$. The limit COULD be 3 but doesn't have to. You wouldn’t be able to determine it as the solution says.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This and the comment on my post made it click. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $ f $ is right-continuous at $ x=7$ then
$$f(7)=\lim_{x\to 7^+}f(x)=L$$

But if we do not have a way to compute $ L $, we cannot get $ f(7)$.

But, if $ f $ is left-continuous at $ x=7 $ then

$$f(7)=\lim_{x\to 7^-}f(x)=3$$
because
$$(\forall x<7)\;\;f(x)=3$$

Comment: Why would it equal 3? Couldn't it be a jump discontinuity at f(7). It could get super close to 3 as x approaches 7 from the left but then jump as it actually reaches x=7 given that f(7)=3 not when x=7 but when x<7......... oh wait but if it were a jump discontinuity coming from the left it wouldn't be continuous which we have established. Is this correct?